# Yii framework with dropzone js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have an add product page with the image upload function.
This snippet is in my view file.

```
<div class="well">
                <?php if ($modelProductitem->imagepath != '') { ?>
                <div class="row oc-img-exist">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 oc-thumbs col-xs-offset-4" data-product-id="<?php echo $modelProductitem->productid; ?>">
                        <a href="#4" class="oc-remove-icon"><i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i></a>
                        <a href="#4" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="<?php echo Octopus::getImagePathProductsWeb ().'/'.$productId.'/'.$modelProductitem->imagepath; ?>" title="<?php echo $modelProductitem->imagepath; ?>">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col-md-12 drop-file dropzone oc-dropzone-previews dropzone-responsive">
                   x
                </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div>
```

in my JS

```
productDropzone = new Dropzone ('#frm-add-product', {

        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl (true); ?>/product/uploadProductImage',
        acceptedFiles: '.png, .PNG, .jpeg, .JPEG, .jpg, .JPG',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        previewsContainer: '.oc-dropzone-previews',
        clickable: '.drop-file',

        init: function() {
            this.on ('complete', function (file) {
                if (productDropzone.getUploadingFiles ().length === 0 && productDropzone.getQueuedFiles ().length === 0) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

In my ProductController , I have this function :-

```
public function actionUploadProductImage () {
        echo "test"; print_r($_POST); 
die();
    }
```

However after clicking on submit there's no error on the dropzone js. The page is just redirected as usual, as though it didn't go through the "actionUploadProductImage" at all.

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> The image files are getting from **$_FILES** but you are using $_POST

```
public function actionUploadProductImage () {
    $ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
    $storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2
     
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
          
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
         
        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
     
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What a stupid mistake I made ! By the way, if I return false in the function, shouldn't that be return as error in the dropzone return value?